# Calling __host__ functions in PyCUDA

Tags: python, pycuda

Is it possible to call `__host__` functions in `pyCUDA` like you can `__global__` functions? I noticed in the documentation that `pycuda.driver.Function` creates a handle to a `__global__` function. `__device__` functions can be called from a `__global__` function, but `__host__` code cannot. I'm aware that using a `__host__` function pretty much defeats the purpose of `pyCUDA`, but there are some already made functions that I'd like to import and call as a proof of concept.

As a note, whenever I try to import the `__host__` function, I get:

```
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuModuleGetFunction failed: named symbol not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible.

This isn't a limitation of PyCUDA, per se, but of CUDA itself. The `__host__` decorator just decays away to plain host code, and the CUDA APIs don't and cannot handle them in the same way that device code can be handled (note the the APIs also don't handle `__device__` either, which is the true equivalent of `__host__`).

If you want to call/use `__host__` functions from Python, you will need to use one of the standard C++/Python interoperability mechanisms, like ctypes or SWIG or boost python, etc.

---

EDIT:

Since this answer was written five years ago, CUDA has added the ability to run host functions in CUDA streams via [cuLaunchHostFunc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gab95a78143bae7f21eebb978f91e7f3f) (driver API) or [cudaLaunchHostFunc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g05841eaa5f90f27124241baafb3e856f). Unfortunately, at the time of this edit (June 2022), PyCUDA doesn't [expose](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/search?q=cuLaunchHostFunc) this functionality, so it still isn't possible in PyCUDA and the core message of the original answer is unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

Below, I'm providing a sample code to call `CUDA API`s in `pyCUDA`. The code generates uniformly distributed random numbers and may serve as a reference to include *already made functions* (as the poster says and like `CUDA API`s) in a `pyCUDA` code.

```
import numpy             as np
import ctypes

import pycuda.driver      as drv
import pycuda.gpuarray    as gpuarray
import pycuda.autoinit

curand = CDLL("/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcurand.so")

# --- Number of elements to generate
N = 10

# --- cuRAND enums
CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT    = 100

# --- Query the cuRAND version
i = c_ulonglong()
curand.curandGetVersion(byref(i))
print("curand version: ", i.value)

# --- Allocate space for generation
d_x = gpuarray.empty(N, dtype = np.float32)

# --- Create random number generator
gen = c_ulonglong()
curand.curandCreateGenerator(byref(gen), CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT)

# --- Generate random numbers
curand.curandGenerateUniform(gen, ctypes.cast(d_x.ptr, POINTER(c_float)), N)

print(d_x)
```

Comment: How did this answer the question "how to call `__host__` functions in PyCUDA"?